# How to detect user input into a form on a webpage

Tags: html, go

I am trying to detect if the user enters something on a webpage hosted by golang but every time the user clicks the button and submits the form it just redirects to a different page (I am hosting on localhost:8080 and it redirects to localhost:8080/text). I am pretty sure this is because the form action is set to "/text" but if I remove that the golang handlefunc is never run. Here is what I have so far:

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
)

func main()() {
  //runs server
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./"))
  http.Handle("/", fs)
  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
  //detects user input and calls function
  http.HandleFunc("/text", textGetter)
}

func textGetter (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) () {
  r.ParseForm()
  text := r.PostFormValue("text")
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "this: %s", text)
  fmt.Print(" was written in the text box")
}
```

and this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Write something bellow</h1>
    <form class="userText" action="/text" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textBox" value="" placeholder="type something here">
      <input type="submit" value="text" name="button" id="button" onclick="thank(message.value)">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You are right that the form contents are set to `/text` because of that being specified in `action`, but you don't specify what you want it to do instead, making this impossible to answer. That is, whether you are fine with it going to `/text` but somehow need to do something else about it, or whether you don't what it to go to `/text` in the first place.

Comment: If you want the textGetter to read the value from the input field with `name="textbox"` change your Go code from `text := r.PostFormValue("text")` to `text := r.PostFormValue("textbox")`.

Comment: @fuglede I am okay if it redirects so long as the textGetter function is run.

Comment: @mkopriva it still doesn't print the text, also thank you both for your help.

Comment: @PersonPerson Actually this `http.HandleFunc("/text", textGetter)` never gets executed because `ListenAndServe` blocks indefinitely, so you need to register the handler before you start listening.

Comment: Okay, thank you, so do I just put it before the listen and serve?

Comment: Yes, just like you do with `fs`, registering of handlers should definitely come before you listen and serve.

Comment: @PersonPerson here's an example of the correct order of calls in your main func: https://play.golang.org/p/1pUaB8pmHY

Answer (score 0):

It’s a front end task independent of Go or any other language.

You may track user input adding `onkeypress` attribute to the interesting field. You need some Ajax library. For example you may take `jQuery`.

Try code similar to:

```
<input ... onkeypress="input()">
<script>
       function input(){
            $.ajax(url, parameters)
       }
 </script>
```